# How to Get a parameter from one place to another in same page in angular 2,4

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template, angular4-forms, angular4-router

I have an interface in which interface  I get a popup search tab with an editable list.

But I am not aware of the method to get data to the main interface for edit after I click this list edit button.
(Like this https://stackblitz.com/angular/xvnyldqvjqp)

Simply what I need is to pass the id of the current item to main edit view as a parameter. (ie, here I have a page name New stock count. In this page, I want to like this. ( When searching an item it will be displayed and then I click to the pencil or the item, the clicked items are displayed in the left side ( Here the clicked items are taking by the parameter named `itemid`, `userid` and `shopid`. But here I didn't get the `itemid` params when using alert I got undefined `itemid`)))
If anybody knows this its a big help for me

**My code:**

[image]

**This is my TS file:**

```
Editmodeclose(value: any) {
    let ItemID: number = this._activatedRoute.snapshot.params['code'];

    alert(this.userid);
    alert(this.shopid);
    alert(ItemID); //(here item id show undefined)
    this._enqService.FetchStockitem(ItemID, this.shopid, this.userid)
      .subscribe(
        defaultdatas => this.defaultdata = defaultdatas,
        error => {
          console.error(error);
          this.statusMessage = "Problem with the service.Please try again after sometime";
      });
    $("#SearchModal").modal("hide");
}
```

My html file(Search item listed html)

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let stocks of stockdetail;">
                    <a [routerLink]="['/NewStockCount',stocks.ItemID]">
                        <div class="row searchItem" style="margin:0px;">
                            <!--search item starts-->
                            <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-12">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">

                                        <label>Item</label>
                                        <span>{{stocks.ItemID}}</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">

                                        <label>Item Code</label>
                                        <span>{{stocks.ItemCode}}</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                        <label>Item Desc</label>
                                        <span>{{stocks.ItemDescription}}</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                        <label>Packing Type</label>
                                        <span>{{stocks.PackingtypeName}}</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                        <label>Stock</label>
                                        <span>{{stocks.Stock}}</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12 text-right">
                                <span class="btn btn-success Editmode-Btn" (click)="Editmodeclose()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>   </ng-container>
```

Left side display item html(want to display items here)

```
  <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Item Code</label>
                                    <ng-container *ngFor="let items of defaultdata;">
                                        <span>{{items.ItemCode}}</span>
                                    </ng-container>
                                  </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>.....etc......
```

Comment: why arent you passing value here (click)="Editmodeclose()"?

Comment: @rohith when click editmodelclose the values can turn to left side

Answer (score 0):

Just pass 'stocks' object in the edit button click, it will work for you.

Some sample code;

```
<span class="btn btn-success Editmode-Btn" (click)="Editmodeclose(**stocks**)">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil">
    </i>
</span>
```